# Proving of $\log(2)=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

any easy hint to prove that
$$\log(2)=1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, the wolfram says $\ln 2$

Comment: $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
$$\ln(2)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-2)^n}{n}=2-\frac{4}{2}+\frac{8}{3}...$$
but this goes down the wrong series....

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Yes, it is. See angryavian's answer.

Comment: @HenryLee you have substituted it incorrectly.

Comment: I did yes. I should have said: $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$ $$=1-\frac 12+\frac 13-\frac 14$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\frac{(2n-1)!}{(2n+1)!} = \frac{1}{(2n)(2n+1)} = \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{2n+1}.$$
Now think about the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$.